# I have duplication problem with parse server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a problem in parse server, for a specific class (table) I used **beforeSave** trigger, like this (for example...) :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("PostsReacts", async (request) => {
  var username = request.user.get("username");
  var post = request.object.get("post");
  var reactsQuery = new Parse.Query("PostsReacts").equalTo("post",post).equalTo("user",username);
  var reacts = await reactsQuery.find();
  if(reacts.length == 1)
  {
    throw "Already reacted on this post."
  }
});
```

***The problem is when I handle a lot of requests at the same time...***

I tried to destroy duplicated objects using **afterSave** trigger, but the problem still exist...
Moreover, I cannot create unique index in **mongodb** because I need to prevent duplicated **user** in each **post** separately, not for all table...